# IOS Swift how can I reload a tableView from a different controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have 2 controllers A and Controller B . Controller A has a TableView and Controller B is a subview that when clicked opens a form and on Submit it enters data into the database. My problem is that I attempt to reload my TableView from Controller B from the user hits submit and I get the following error
**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value** from this line

```
 self.TableSource.reloadData()
```

Now the data from Controller B is successfully inserted so after I restart my app the data I submit is there . This is my code (TableSource is the TableView outlet)

**Controller A**

```
  func reloadTable(latmin: Float,latmax: Float,lonmin: Float, lonmax: Float) {
        let url:URL = URL(string:ConnectionString+"MY-URL")!



        let session = URLSession.shared
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData
        let parameter = "parameters"
        request.httpBody = parameter.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        session.dataTask(with:request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {

            } else {
                do {

                    let parsed = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]



                    if let S = parsedData["myData"] as? [AnyObject]            {


                        for A in Data {
                           // gets Json Data

                                       }

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    // This is what I named my TableView
                            self.TableSource.reloadData()

                        }
                    }

                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error)
                }

            }

        }).resume()


    }
```

That is my HTTP-Request that gets data from the database, now in that same Controller A I have a button that when clicked opens the SubView to Controller B and this is the code

```
  @IBAction func Post_Action(_ sender: Any) {
        let Popup = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ControllerB") as! Controller B

        self.addChildViewController(Popup)
        Popup.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(Popup.view)
        Popup.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
```

This is the code in **Controller B** and this is how I try to reload the TableView in Controller A

```
@IBAction func Submit_Form(_ sender: Any) {

  // Code that submits the form no issues here


        latmin = 32.18
       latmax = 32.50
       lonmin = -81.12
       lonmax = -81.90

     let Homepage = ControllerA()
       Homepage.reloadTable(latmin: latmin!,latmax: latmax!,lonmin: lonmin!,lonmax: lonmax!)

    }
```

So as stated before Controller A loads the data from the Database, Controller B has a form and when submitted it enters new data into the database . That whole process works I just now want to update the TableView in Controller A from the form is submitted in Controller B

Comment: In Submit_Form you are creating an instance of ControllerA(), this is going to be an entirely different instance from what you have originally. I think you need to review the difference between a class and an instance of a class and how this relates to view controllers being created in storyboards. *IF* Controller B really is a controller, you could simply refresh the data in Controller A in viewDidAppear which  will be called when the form is dismissed. However seems to me Controller B may not be a controller and you are incorrectly describing it (because you say "Controller B is a subview")

Comment: In other words, the correct solution to how you should architect this cannot be given until you precisely show what you call Controller B is and how it is invoked from Controller A. As a side comment - having your http fetching code in the view controller itself, and always being re-called, is not a good idea. You might want to look into moving it to a model class.

Comment: Oh ok thanks I will work on that first and move my Http code to a model class as I am still learning the correct way to do things in swift .

Comment: you can do it with `nsnotifications`

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using protocol:

```
protocol SomeActionDelegate {
    func didSomeAction()
}
```

In ViewController B

```
var delegate: SomeActionDelegate?
```

In ViewController A when segue

```
viewControllerB.delegate = self
```

You should add this

```
extension ViewControllerA: SomeActionDelegate {
    func didSomeAction() {
         self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

And in ViewController B

```
 func didChangeSomething() {
      self.delegate?.didSomeAction()
 }
```

It works like when ViewController B `didChangeSomething()` it sends message to ViewController A that it should `didSomeAction()`

Answer (score 2):

**You can do it with NSNotification**

**in swift 3.0**

Think you have two viwe controllers called `viewcontrollerA` and `viewControllerB`

- `viewcontrollerA` has the tableview.
- you need to reload it from `viewcontrolerB`

**implementaion of viewcontrollerA**

create a function to relod your tableview in `viewcontrollerA` and call it in `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let notificationNme = NSNotification.Name("NotificationIdf")
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourControllername.reloadTableview), name: notificationNme, object: nil)
}

func relodaTableview() {
    self.TableSource.reloadData()
}
```

**implementation in viewcontrollerB (where you want to reload tableview)**

post the notification `in button click or anywhere you want like below`

```
 let notificationNme = NSNotification.Name("NotificationIdf")
 NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationNme, object: nil)
```

**hope this will help to you.**